# Autofac to inject NLog instance in every DataContract at service side of wire

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac, nlog, datacontract

Using WCF, I have `DataContract` equivalence in place at client and business (service) end. I simply want a NLog instance to be injected in every `DataContract` w.r.t its own type via Autofac.

I followed this [link](https://gist.github.com/pawelpabich/3066496) but it appears that this approach is only workable when use Autofac container to resolve this type. In my scenario `AssemblyFunctionLibrary` instance is created by WCF internally without even calling constructor.

My question is how can i possibly inject Logger instance in every `DataContract` with its own type?

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class AssemblyFunctionLibrary : EndPoint
{
    public Logger Logger { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LibraryPath { get; set; }
}
```

**Autofac Registrations**

```
builder.RegisterModule<NLogModule>();

foreach (var assembly in KnownTypesFinder.GetPluginAssemblies())
{
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .AsSelf()
        .PropertiesAutowired();
}
```

Comment: Curious as to why you want to inject anything (let alone a logger instance) into a DataContract?  DataContracts exist to serialize data across the wire - there normally shouldn't be any functionality in them.

Comment: There are [a lot of questions about injection of data contracts](https://www.google.com/search?q=wcf+datacontract+injection) and they're either not solved or they were solved by restructuring so the injection wasn't done to the data object. There's no hook in WCF for IoC into data objects - not an Autofac shortcoming, but a problem in WCF. You may not get an answer to this question.

Comment: @Tim, my DataContracts have behaviors which requires logging. The question remains even if i use Business classes instead. How to have logging instance with respect to each Type who is responsible to log.

Comment: @TravisIllig, i hope there must be some workaround might have been done by some experts out there or do you have any post describing this shortcoming as an evidence?